# Macbook Pro 8.1 Wireless Instructions

Tags: 11.10, wireless, drivers, macbook

I have been following some instructions on how to get the wireless card working on my early 2011 MBP running Ubuntu 11.10. These can be found [here](http://homepage.uibk.ac.at/~c705283/archives/2011/09/04/linux_support_for_broadcom_4331_wireless_chip_macbook_pro_81/index.html).

I get to the following steps:

`Extract the firmware:`

> $ tar xf ../broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
>
> $ export FIRMWARE_INSTALL_DIR="/lib/firmware"
>
> $ sudo ./b43-fwcutter -w "$FIRMWARE_INSTALL_DIR" 
>   broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
>
> $ cd ..

and the following error is produced in terminal:

`sudo ./b43-fwcutter -w ¨$FIRMWARE_INSTALL_DIR¨ broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o`

> This file is recognised as:
>
> filename   :  wl_apsta.o
>
> version    :  666.2
>
> MD5        :  *********************************
>
> Extracting b43/lp0initvals14.fw
>
> failed to create output directory: No such file or directory

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated as I would like to be able to make my laptop a portable machine running Ubuntu. Currently, it is a desktop laptop machine...

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the directory `/lib/firmware` first (at least I guess that's why it fails; I might be wrong):

```
sudo mkdir -p /lib/firmware
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the Broadcom Corp. drivers work for a Macbook Pro 5,2 model under 12.10. I had to wrestle with the drivers in 12.04, but under 12.10 (with the kernel updates and all) I simply had to install them from Software Sources -> Additional Drivers.